# Повсеместное использование r-value ссылок

Tags: c++, c++11

Стоит ли повсеместно стараться как можно чаще использовать *r-value* ссылки? Вот, допустим, код:

```
std::string hi() {
    return "hello world\n"
}

auto&& str = hi();
```

В данном случае в строке 5 происходит лишь одно создание объекта, и *r-value* ссылка на него, и никакого копирования... эффективно, если сравнить, например, с:

```
auto str = hi();
```

или

```
auto str = std::move(hi());
```

Посему на первый взгляд напрашивается вывод: почему бы не создавать *r-value* ссылки как можно чаще вместо обычной инициализации переменной? Особенно если нужно создавать 100000 раз в секунду эти переменные. Допустим, если можно, то писать так:

```
void function() {
    int&& a = 1;
    double&& b = 2.;
    auto&& value = return_value();
    /*далее какой-то код*/
}
```

и далее работать с этими ссылками или передавать их в другое место... выглядит, это чуть более монстрообразно, чем обычная инициализация переменных, к которой глаз привык:

```
void function() {
    int a = 1;
    double b = 2.;
    auto value = return_value();
    /*далее какой-то код*/
}
```

Поэтому стоит ли как можно чаще пользоваться *r-value* ссылками вместо обычной инициализации новых переменных в локальном контексте(внутри функций, например) для эффективности, или есть ли какие-то встроенные оптимизации, которые при `int a = 2` делают те же действия, что и `int&& a = 2`?

Comment: Вообще-то что-то не могу сообразить, на какой выигрыш вы намекаете? В чем, по-вашему, преимущество `int&&a = 2;` перед `int a = 2;`?

Comment: не судите строго: я думал, что int a = 2 копируется 2 в переменную а... в случае же int&& a = 2 никакого копирования нету, есть лишь aliasing для временного объекта 2... может я не прав

Comment: @xperious: В общем случае константы не создают заранее временных объектов в памяти, к которым можно было бы привязать ссылку. Для того, чтобы сделать  `int&& a = 2` во время выполнения будет формироваться временный объект типа `int` и инициализироваться значением 2. А это то же самое, что и `int a = 2`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Обычно ссылки хранятся в памяти в виде указателей на объекты. Поэтому в данном предложении

```
auto &&a = 1;
```

будет создан временный объект со значением `1` и ссылка на него.

Если у вас есть объявление вида

```
auto a = f();
```

где функция `f` возвращает объект некоторого типа `T`, то этот объект, возвращаемый из функции, строится на месте переменной `a` , минуя вызов копирующего или перемещающего конструктора.

Рассмотрите следующий пример

```
#include <iostream>

struct Int
{
    Int( int x = 0 ) : x( x )
    { 
        std::cout << "Int::Int( int )" << std::endl; 
    }

    Int( const Int &rhs ) : x( rhs.x )  
    { 
        std::cout << "Int::Int( const Int & )" << std::endl; 
    }

    Int( Int &&rhs ) : x( rhs.x )  
    { 
        std::cout << "Int::Int( Int && )" << std::endl; 
    }

    ~Int()
    { 
        std::cout << "Int::~Int()" << std::endl; 
    }

    int x;
};

Int f( int x ) { return x; }

int main() 
{
    auto x = f( 10 );
    auto &&y = f( 20 );

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод на консоль будет следующим

```
Int::Int( int )
Int::Int( int )
Int::~Int()
Int::~Int()
```

То есть в обоих случаях будет вызвано по одному конструктору и, соответственно, деструктору.

К тому же нельзя создавать, например, массивы из ссылок. В нижеприведенной программе, если раскомментировать предложение с массивом ссылок, то будет выдано сообщение об ошибке.

```
#include <iostream>

struct Int
{
    Int( int x = 0 ) : x( x )
    { 
        std::cout << "Int::Int( int )" << std::endl; 
    }

    Int( const Int &rhs ) : x( rhs.x )  
    { 
        std::cout << "Int::Int( const Int & )" << std::endl; 
    }

    Int( Int &&rhs ) : x( rhs.x )  
    { 
        std::cout << "Int::Int( Int && )" << std::endl; 
    }

    ~Int()
    { 
        std::cout << "Int::~Int()" << std::endl; 
    }

    int x;
};

Int f( int x ) { return x; }

int main() 
{
    Int a[] = { f( 10 ) };
    //Int &&b[] = { f( 10 ) };

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Если добавить в Ваш первый пример `-fno-elide-constructors`, результаты будут несколько иными.

Comment: @alexolut А зачем добавлять и осложнять себе жизнь?:)

Comment: Хотя бы чтобы показать различие, и возможности по оптимизации компилятором *не-ссылок* даже без каких-либо явных опций.

Comment: но можно, использовать константную ссылку на массив или r-value ссылку на массив const Int(&ref)[5] = { 1 };  Int(&&ref_)[5] = { 2 };

Answer (score 6):

На самом деле доступ к переменной напрямую всегда быстрее чем по ссылке.
Составим простую программу:

```
int O() {
    int x = 5;
    return x;
}

int test(){
  auto&& value = O();
  return value;
}

int test2(){
   auto value = O();
  return value;
}
```

Соберём БЕЗ оптимизаций.

```
test():
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        sub     rsp, 16
        call    O()
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-12], eax
        lea     rax, [rbp-12]
        mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-8], rax
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-8]
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rax]
        leave
        ret
test2():
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        sub     rsp, 16
        call    O()
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], eax
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-4]
        leave
        ret
```

Как видите работа напрямую - меньше операций сразу, хотя мы переменную и не использовали считай. В общем для примитивов однозначно лучше переменная, для сложных классов - воспользуйтесь профайлером (возможно есть смысл использовать перемещающий конструктор или что-то такое).

Comment: хм, да, моя идея про повсеместное использование r-value reference не верна была... это если без оптимизаций

Comment: Ну, ээээ, то, что без оптимизаций компилятор собирает глупый код, это ж не аргумент. Если семантика кода одинаковая, то в идеальном случае компилятор должен произвести и одинаковый код.

Comment: @VladD безусловно на -O2 код одинаковый, но там и вызова функции нет. А вдруг код сложнее? В любом случае в плане оптимизации ссылка _не лучше_ переменной.

Comment: @pavel: Ну, да, но так можно дойти до того, что и код типа `for (auto x : container)` заменять на цикл со счётчиком из соображений, что оптимизатор может не справиться. Мне кажется, главными соображениями должны быть соображения ясности, читабельности и лёгкости поддержки.

Comment: @pavel отказываемся от ссылок и начинаем передавать большие объекты по значению?

Comment: @alexolut нет конечно) может я в ответе слово профайлер недостаточно чётко выделил. Есть же много способов начиная от передачи *в* функцию по ссылке и заканчивая глобальной переменной...

Answer (score 5):

В данном случае нет никакой практической разницы между

```
auto str = hi();
```

и

```
auto&& str = hi();
```

В обоих случаях copy elision и return value optimization приводят к тому, что результат функции `hi` будет формироваться (конструироваться) напрямую в финальном объекте. В первом случае - напрямую в `str`. Во-втором случае - напрямую во временном объекте, к которому будет привязываться `str`.

Comment: все-таки не понятно... вот есть объект, который весит 2мб допустим... у него сложный конструктор копирования и перемещения(пусть имеется глубокое копирование)... неужели при auto ref = return_value(); сработает стопроцентно rvo и не выгоднее писать auto&& ref = return_value()?

Comment: @xperious: Сложность конструктора и тяжесть объекта тут ни на что не влияет. Влияет лишь желание компилятора работать по схеме такой прямой конструкции. В С++17, кстати, многие из таких оптимизаций (если не все) становятся гарантированными. Но и в нынешнем С++ они прекрасно работают, в чем вы можете запросто убедиться на практике.